# Make LyX Configuration Emulate to Scientific Workplace Workspace

Tags: lyx, scientific-workplace

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a customization of LyX (or similar program) that emulates the workspace found in Scientific Workplace. So, for instance, similar colors, toolbar locations, ways of doing things, etc. I know that it can be customized extensively but want to make sure that nothing of the kind exists before attempting something like this myself.

A quick explanation: I am writing a paper with a (senior) co-author who insists on using Scientific Workplace. No amount of gentle prodding or compatibility-related headaches has made him reconsider his choice of software. Our paper requires formatting that is easy to do in plain LaTeX or LyX but a pain in SWP. There is no Linux version of SWP (my OS) and I haven't got the cash to pay for it(!). I hope that, if I can make everything appear to be the same in LyX, I can get him to convert. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only useful information I have is that you can use SWP shortcuts (or a good approximation of them). To do so, go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts. Click on "Browse" and choose "sciword.bind". Please let me know if you have any improvements to the bind file (I've done a lot of work on it). I don't know of attempts to emulate SWP in any other way.

Comment: Great, will do. It seems easy enough to change around coloring, math previewing, toolbar location and so forth. After that it seems like the only way to get it closer is to make things harder! 4x3 table module, anyone?

Comment: One point to consider is that SWP does not support `etex` extensions, which will make it incompatible with a lot of modern packages.

Comment: I think it's a good question aiming towards seamless migration from SWP to LyX. If at some point no longer on hold, could you possibly provide a SWP screenshot detailing the layout you would sought?